# How to print a R dataframe with colors?

Tags: r, dataframe, ansi-colors, crayon

With the **crayon** package, one can create colored strings:

```
library(crayon)
dat <- data.frame(X=c(yellow("foobar"), green("baz")), Y = cyan("qux"))
```

Here is the encoded `dat`:

```
> dat
                       X                   Y
1 \033[33mfoobar\033[39m \033[36mqux\033[39m
2    \033[32mbaz\033[39m \033[36mqux\033[39m
```

With `write.table`, one can get the table with the colors:

[image]

But the alignment is lost. How to get the colored dataframe with a nice alignment?

The [colorDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorDF/vignettes/colorDF.html) package allows to set colors in a dataframe, but does not allow to do what I want. What I want is to be able to color one word say in red at every occurrence of this word in a column. The `df_search` function of **colorDF** is close to what I want, but it colors the entire cells where the pattern is found, I want to color one word only.

For example, in this dataframe:

```
#                                file line              code
# 1                        folder/f.R    1 f <- function(x){
# 2              folder/subfolder/g.R    1 g <- function(y){
# 3 folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/h.R    1 h <- function(z){
```

I want the word `function` in the `code` column to be red.

Comment: Miles McBain posted something about the {paint} package on twitter today (https://twitter.com/MilesMcBain/status/1421104940441907208?s=20) - perhaps that package could be adapted to suit your needs? Or maybe the [colortable package](https://github.com/thebioengineer/colortable) could work?

Comment: Ah no, it colors the entire cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `tibble` instead of a `data.frame` as it allows to print vectors nicely, see `vignette("pillar", package = "vctrs")`.

In particular :

> You can get basic control over how a vector is printed in a tibble by providing a format() method

To answer your question, you could create a `function_red` class extending `character`, see `vignette("s3-vector", package = "vctrs")`:

```
library(vctrs)

data <- read.table(text="file line code
'folder/f.R' 1 'f <- function(x){'
'folder/subfolder/g.R' 1 'g <- function(y){'
'folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/h.R' 1 'h <- function(z){'
",header=T)

function_red <- function(x = character()) {
  vec_assert(x, character())
  new_vctr(x, class = "vctrs_function_red")
}

format.vctrs_function_red <- function(x,...) {
  gsub("function",crayon::red("function"),vec_data(x))
}

data$code <- function_red(data$code)
tibble::tibble(data)
```

[image]